# Which searching mechanism does ANY keyword in Postgres use?

Tags: postgresql

Behind the scenes how is Postgres keyword **ANY** is implemented ?
Does it use Binary search or Sequential search ? to find the element in an array of varchars?

Eg: Some arrays can be of size 1 million

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in [`ExecEvalHashedScalarArrayOp`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/executor/execExprInterp.c;h=9b9bbf00a9727250ee510d4ff07e57e01ac9ef30;hb=HEAD#l3504) in `src/backend/executor/execExprInterp.c`. The function comment says it all:

```
/*
 * Evaluate "scalar op ANY (const array)".
 *
 * Similar to ExecEvalScalarArrayOp, but optimized for faster repeat lookups
 * by building a hashtable on the first lookup.  This hashtable will be reused
 * by subsequent lookups.  Unlike ExecEvalScalarArrayOp, this version only
 * supports OR semantics.
 *
 * Source array is in our result area, scalar arg is already evaluated into
 * fcinfo->args[0].
 *
 * The operator always yields boolean.
 */
```

Use the source, Luke!